# Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics

In math tests a student has an average score of 80 with a standard deviation of 6. Her friend has a mean of 78 with a standard deviation of 8. What is the probability that her friend gets a better result than she does on this math test?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Denote with $X$ the student's score and with $Y$ the friend's score. Note that the random variable which expresses the difference between their scores i.e. $$D:=X-Y$$ is again normally distributed (as difference of normal random variables) with mean $$μ_D=μ_Χ-μ_Y=80-78=2$$ and variance $$σ^2_D=σ^2_Χ\color{blue}{+}σ^2_Y=6^2+8^2=100 \implies σ_D=10$$ Thus in symbols $$D \sim N(μ_D=2, σ_D=10)$$ You want to calculate the probability $$P(X<Y)=P(X-Y<0)=P(D<0)$$

---

The parameters $μ_D$ and $σ_D$ are derived as follows: $$μ_D=E[D]=E[X-Y]=E[X]-E[Y]=μ_Χ-μ_Y$$
and $$σ^2_D=Var(D)=Var(X-Y)=Var(X)+(-1)^2Var(Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)=σ^2_Χ+σ^2_Y$$ (and not "-" because the sign in front of $Y$ is squared when it comes in front of the variance).

Comment: I understand that the difference of normal random variables is normal distribution but how is the standard deviation the sum of variance?

Comment: @Ivy See my edit.